# Problems with ajax development

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I apologize in advance for my bad English.
I have site in development http://plast-pak.esy.es/ on html-coding
With Ajax i called html page into my front page and slider is SlideUp.

```
<button onclick="clickAlert();" class="clickDown">?????????</button>

<script>

    function clickAlert() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: 'item-1.html',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#projectInformation').html(response).slideDown('fast');
                }
            });
            $('.front-page > #main_wrap').slideUp(3000);
            $('.front-page > #menuBar').slideUp(3000);
        });
    }

</script>
```

Was callback page with information. It have her own button, witch have to close this page and return front page.

```
<button onclick="clickAbort();" class="clickUp">????????? ?? ???????</button>

<script>

    function clickAbort() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('.front-page > #main_wrap').slideDown(3000);
            $('.front-page > #menuBar').slideDown(3000);
            $('#projectInformation .full-node').remove();
        });
    }

</script>
```

In the end, everything works, how it works. All horrible and very incorrect. Please help me to understand why it all works so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably better suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Which part are you having a hard time. "All horrible and very incorrect" is such a poor description. How about "I expected A but B happened"

Comment: Code makes no sense $(this) is the window object and you are adding a click event to it??

Comment: @MLeFevre this is not code review material...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your advices. The problem was solved as follows:

```
<button id="alert" onclick="clickAlert();" class="clickDown">Подробнее</button>
    function clickAlert() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: 'item-1.html',
                    success: function(response) {
                        ...
                    }
                });
                ...
        }
```

for whatever reason, Slider not given use following code

```
$("#alert").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: 'item-1.html',
        success: function(response) {
             $('#projectInformation').html(response).slideDown('fast');
        }
    });
    $('.front-page > #main_wrap').slideUp(3000);
    $('.front-page > #menuBar').slideUp(3000);
```

Only click event in button is working. Thanks again for your advice

Answer (score 2):

Remove

`$(this).click(function(){`

from `clickAlert` and `clickAbort`. They are already click handlers.

Other than that, you will have to be more specific about "horrible and very incorrect".

Answer (score 2):

$(this).click() is used to setup a handler for the click event of the button, and you're already doing that by setting the onclick attribute in your markup.
The usual way to do this is by giving an id to the button, so that you can set events in the javascript code:

```
<button id="alert" class="clickDown">Подробнее</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#alert").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: 'item-1.html',
        success: function(response) {
             $('#projectInformation').html(response).slideDown('fast');
        }
    });
    $('.front-page > #main_wrap').slideUp(3000);
    $('.front-page > #menuBar').slideUp(3000);
});
</script>
```